# Download webcrawler output from Dirbuster

Tags: web-browser

Hello security experts,

I've made a wordlist to search some content on a specific webserver. DirBuster found a list of 500 images, is there a way to download them all on my computer.

Kind regards

Comment: I am not sure, what has this question to do with information security...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick pipe into cut into xargs wget or any other simple scripting should do the trick. Google is very capable of helping with the sort of problems.